# How to access Android notifications with a Toga app

Tags: python, android, push-notification, notifications, beeware

I am trying to build an app with Toga/Beeware, mainly for Android but ideally cross-platform. I need the app to send push notifications at user-specified times. I see [some have previously attempted the same challenge](https://github.com/beeware/toga/issues/907), but [there's currently no official documentation](https://github.com/beeware/beeware/issues/163). Has anyone accomplished this? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/blob/12.0.1/demo/app/src/main/python/chaquopy/demo/ui_demo.py#L81) has an example of calling the Android notification API from Python:

```py
        from android.content import Context
        from androidx.core.app import NotificationCompat

        builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, App.DEFAULT_CHANNEL)
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        builder.setContentTitle(
            activity.getString(R.string.demo_notify_title))
        builder.setContentText(
            activity.getString(R.string.demo_notify_text))
        activity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)\
            .notify(0, builder.getNotification())
```

Notes:

- With Toga, the `activity` in this example should be replaced with `self._impl.native`, where `self` is your `App` object.
- `DEFAULT_CHANNEL` should be set up with code similar to [this](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/blob/12.0.1/demo/app/src/utils/java/com/chaquo/python/utils/App.java#L23).
- The `activity.getString` calls can be replaced with any string you want.

Unfortunately, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 33 or higher, which is now the case with the default BeeWare Android template, you'll need to ask permission before showing a notification, and I don't have a Python example of that.

`targetSdkVersion` 33 or higher will be required by Google Play starting in August 2023. But if you're not going to distribute your app on Google Play, you can work around this issue by using the [`build_gradle_extra_content`](https://briefcase.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/platforms/android.html#build-gradle-extra-content) option:

```
build_gradle_extra_content = "android.defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion 32"
```